# geoserver returns black image on aerials

Tags: image, tiff, geoserver

I am trying to upload aerial photos to geoserver to be shown as background. But everytime the image is black instead of detailed satellite image. Also tried on single tif files, but same result. Anybody have experience with this issue and know a solution?

I use ImageMosaic as plugin to upload the tifs.

This is the result of gdalinfo:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.8\bin>gdalinfo --format GTIFF D:\tile-20000-380000.tif

Format Details:

  Short Name: GTiff

  Long Name: GeoTIFF

  Supports: Raster

  Extensions: tif tiff

  Mime Type: image/tiff

  Help Topic: frmt_gtiff.html

  Supports: Subdatasets

  Supports: Open() - Open existing dataset.

  Supports: Create() - Create writable dataset.

  Supports: CreateCopy() - Create dataset by copying another.

  Supports: Virtual IO - eg. /vsimem/

  Creation Datatypes: Byte UInt16 Int16 UInt32 Int32 Float32 Float64 CInt16 CInt32 CFloat32 CFloat64

 

<CreationOptionList>

  <Option name="COMPRESS" type="string-select">

    <Value>NONE</Value>

    <Value>LZW</Value>

    <Value>PACKBITS</Value>

    <Value>JPEG</Value>

    <Value>CCITTRLE</Value>

    <Value>CCITTFAX3</Value>

    <Value>CCITTFAX4</Value>

    <Value>DEFLATE</Value>

    <Value>LZMA</Value>

    <Value>ZSTD</Value>

    <Value>WEBP</Value>

    <Value>LERC</Value>

    <Value>LERC_DEFLATE</Value>

   <Value>LERC_ZSTD</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="PREDICTOR" type="int" description="Predictor Type (1=default, 2=horizontal differencing, 3=floating point prediction)" />

  <Option name="DISCARD_LSB" type="string" description="Number of least-significant bits to set to clear as a single value or comma-separated list of values for per-band values" />

  <Option name="JPEG_QUALITY" type="int" description="JPEG quality 1-100" default="75" />

  <Option name="JPEGTABLESMODE" type="int" description="Content of JPEGTABLES tag. 0=no JPEGTABLES tag, 1=Quantization tables only, 2=Huffman tables only, 3=Both" default="1" />

  <Option name="ZLEVEL" type="int" description="DEFLATE compression level 1-9" default="6" />

  <Option name="LZMA_PRESET" type="int" description="LZMA compression level 0(fast)-9(slow)" default="6" />

  <Option name="ZSTD_LEVEL" type="int" description="ZSTD compression level 1(fast)-22(slow)" default="9" />

  <Option name="MAX_Z_ERROR" type="float" description="Maximum error for LERC compression" default="0" />

  <Option name="WEBP_LOSSLESS" type="boolean" description="Whether lossless compression should be used" default="FALSE" />

  <Option name="WEBP_LEVEL" type="int" description="WEBP quality level. Low values result in higher compression ratios" default="75" />

  <Option name="NUM_THREADS" type="string" description="Number of worker threads for compression. Can be set to ALL_CPUS" default="1" />

  <Option name="NBITS" type="int" description="BITS for sub-byte files (1-7), sub-uint16 (9-15), sub-uint32 (17-31), or float32 (16)" />

  <Option name="INTERLEAVE" type="string-select" default="PIXEL">

    <Value>BAND</Value>

    <Value>PIXEL</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="TILED" type="boolean" description="Switch to tiled format" />

  <Option name="TFW" type="boolean" description="Write out world file" />

  <Option name="RPB" type="boolean" description="Write out .RPB (RPC) file" />

  <Option name="RPCTXT" type="boolean" description="Write out _RPC.TXT file" />

  <Option name="BLOCKXSIZE" type="int" description="Tile Width" />

  <Option name="BLOCKYSIZE" type="int" description="Tile/Strip Height" />

  <Option name="PHOTOMETRIC" type="string-select">

    <Value>MINISBLACK</Value>

    <Value>MINISWHITE</Value>

    <Value>PALETTE</Value>

    <Value>RGB</Value>

    <Value>CMYK</Value>

    <Value>YCBCR</Value>

    <Value>CIELAB</Value>

    <Value>ICCLAB</Value>

    <Value>ITULAB</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="SPARSE_OK" type="boolean" description="Should empty blocks be omitted on disk?" default="FALSE" />

  <Option name="ALPHA" type="string-select" description="Mark first extrasample as being alpha">

    <Value>NON-PREMULTIPLIED</Value>

    <Value>PREMULTIPLIED</Value>

    <Value>UNSPECIFIED</Value>

    <Value aliasOf="NON-PREMULTIPLIED">YES</Value>

    <Value aliasOf="UNSPECIFIED">NO</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="PROFILE" type="string-select" default="GDALGeoTIFF">

    <Value>GDALGeoTIFF</Value>

    <Value>GeoTIFF</Value>

    <Value>BASELINE</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="PIXELTYPE" type="string-select">

    <Value>DEFAULT</Value>

    <Value>SIGNEDBYTE</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="BIGTIFF" type="string-select" description="Force creation of BigTIFF file">

    <Value>YES</Value>

    <Value>NO</Value>

    <Value>IF_NEEDED</Value>

    <Value>IF_SAFER</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="ENDIANNESS" type="string-select" default="NATIVE" description="Force endianness of created file. For DEBUG purpose mostly">

    <Value>NATIVE</Value>

    <Value>INVERTED</Value>

    <Value>LITTLE</Value>

    <Value>BIG</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS" type="boolean" default="NO" description="Force copy of overviews of source dataset (CreateCopy())" />

  <Option name="SOURCE_ICC_PROFILE" type="string" description="ICC profile" />

  <Option name="SOURCE_PRIMARIES_RED" type="string" description="x,y,1.0 (xyY) red chromaticity" />

  <Option name="SOURCE_PRIMARIES_GREEN" type="string" description="x,y,1.0 (xyY) green chromaticity" />

  <Option name="SOURCE_PRIMARIES_BLUE" type="string" description="x,y,1.0 (xyY) blue chromaticity" />

  <Option name="SOURCE_WHITEPOINT" type="string" description="x,y,1.0 (xyY) whitepoint" />

  <Option name="TIFFTAG_TRANSFERFUNCTION_RED" type="string" description="Transfer function for red" />

  <Option name="TIFFTAG_TRANSFERFUNCTION_GREEN" type="string" description="Transfer function for green" />

  <Option name="TIFFTAG_TRANSFERFUNCTION_BLUE" type="string" description="Transfer function for blue" />

  <Option name="TIFFTAG_TRANSFERRANGE_BLACK" type="string" description="Transfer range for black" />

  <Option name="TIFFTAG_TRANSFERRANGE_WHITE" type="string" description="Transfer range for white" />

  <Option name="STREAMABLE_OUTPUT" type="boolean" default="NO" description="Enforce a mode compatible with a streamable file" />

  <Option name="GEOTIFF_KEYS_FLAVOR" type="string-select" default="STANDARD" description="Which flavor of GeoTIFF keys must be used">

    <Value>STANDARD</Value>

    <Value>ESRI_PE</Value>

  </Option>

</CreationOptionList>

 

<OpenOptionList>

  <Option name="NUM_THREADS" type="string" description="Number of worker threads for compression. Can be set to ALL_CPUS" default="1" />

  <Option name="GEOTIFF_KEYS_FLAVOR" type="string-select" default="STANDARD" description="Which flavor of GeoTIFF keys must be used (for writing)">

    <Value>STANDARD</Value>

    <Value>ESRI_PE</Value>

  </Option>

  <Option name="GEOREF_SOURCES" type="string" description="Comma separated list made with values INTERNAL/TABFILE/WORLDFILE/PAM/NONE that describe the priority order for georeferencing" default="PAM,INTERNAL,TABFILE,WORLDFILE" />

  <Option name="SPARSE_OK" type="boolean" description="Should empty blocks be omitted on disk?" default="FALSE" />

</OpenOptionList>
```

Other metadata items:

```
LIBTIFF=INTERNAL
```

Comment: please add more details on how you add the images, the `gdalinfo` output of one of the images, and what the geoserver log file shows using the [edit] function

Answer (score 0):

We recently found out the compression type was wrong. WEBP instead of Geotiff. It will be resolved.